# How to Retrieve character string from IntPtr

Tags: c#, pointers, vb6

I call a P/Invoke DLL function which is made for vb6.

It works.. my previous question was about getting it to work I managed to get it to run but now I cannot retrieve the full string from it's output.

The DLL Function and it's structures are declared like this.

```
static class ModuleASM
{

    public struct REGTYPE
    {
        public byte REG_Kind; // ;1=8 bits \ 2=16 bits \ 3=32 bits \ 4=MMX \ 5=XMM \ 6=Float stack \ 7=Segment \ 8=Debug \ 9=Control \ 10=Test
        public byte REG_Ptr_Kind; // ;1=Byte PTR \ 2=Word PTR \ 3=Dword PTR \ 4=Qword PTR \ 5=mmword ptr \ 6=xmmword ptr \ 7=FWord PTR \ 8=tbyte ptr \ 9=null ptr (LEA)
        public byte REG_Type; //  ;0-7= direct register index \ 16 register=byte && 7 \ 32 register=(byte && 63)/8 \ 64=[32/16 address only] \ 128=[using x86 relatives]
        public byte REG_BaseAsReg; // ? ;1=Register only (BASE exposed)!
    }

    public struct REGSTRUCT
    {
        public uint SEG_TYPE;
        public uint Base;
        public uint INDEX;
        public uint SCALE;
        public uint DISPLACEMENTS;
        public uint DISPLACEMENT_TYPE;
        public ModuleASM.REGTYPE REG_Kind;
        public uint PTR_TYPE;
    }

    public struct IMMSTRUCT
    {
        public uint VALUE_LO;
        public uint VALUE_HI;
        public uint VALUE_TYPE; //     1=Byte \ 2=Word \ 4=Dword \ 8=ByteToWord \ 16=ByteToDword \ 32=AbsJump \ 64=ShortJump \ 128=LongJump
    }


    public struct DisAsmStruct
    {
        public uint Instruction_Prefix;
        public uint Instruction;
        public ModuleASM.REGSTRUCT Reg1;
        public ModuleASM.REGSTRUCT Reg2;
        public uint Reg_Reg; //1=from ptr
        public ModuleASM.IMMSTRUCT Imm;
        public uint Instruction_Length;
    }

    [DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int DisAssemble(IntPtr Data, uint BaseAddress, out IntPtr DisAsmString, out DisAsmStruct DisAsmS, uint DisasmOpt);
}

//FDATA is the file data it's a huge byte array.

uint BufferLength;
uint CNT;
uint BaseAddress = 0x401000;

//The call is like this
unsafe
{
    string Opcodes = new string((char)0, 128);
    IntPtr OpcodesTest;
    ModuleASM.DisAsmStruct DisAa = new ModuleASM.DisAsmStruct();
    fixed (byte* dataPtr = &GLOBALDATA.FDATA[CNT])
    {
        IntPtr dataBuf = new IntPtr((void*)dataPtr);
        BufferLength = ModuleASM.DisAssemble(dataBuf, BaseAddress + CNT, out OpcodesTest, out DisAa, 0);

        //Kinda like it.. need more characters like, PUSH ECX
        ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(OpcodesTest.ToInt64())) //return "PUSH\0\0\0\0"

        byte testbbb = Marshal.ReadByte(OpcodesTest); //fail error
        string testa = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(OpcodesTest)); //fail error
        string testb = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(OpcodesTest); //blank return
        string testc = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(OpcodesTest); //fail error
        string testd = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(OpcodesTest)); //fail error
        string teste = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(OpcodesTest)); //fail error
        string testf = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(OpcodesTest); //fail error
    }
}
```

Anyone know what I have to do to fix so I can get the full string? not just the first 4 letters.. like the one example is suppose to show 8 characters.

Originally declared in vb6 like so

```
Declare Function DisAssemble Lib "disASM" (Data As Any, ByVal BaseAddress As Long, DisAsmString As Any, DisAsmS As Any, ByVal DisasmOpt As Long) As Long

Dim Opcodes     As String
Opcodes = String(128, 0)
Dim CleanOpCode As String
Dim DisA As DisAsmStruct

BufferLength = DisAssemble(FDATA(CNT), BaseAddress + CNT, ByVal Opcodes, DisA, 0)
CleanOpCode = Left(Opcodes, BufferLength)
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with vb6.

Comment: ok? what is your problem?

Comment: i have no problem, but you have one to solve. my first comment was just a hint to help. but it seems that you are not that wise.

Comment: @milevyo you were demonstrating aggressive tendentious towards me, it has vb6 code at the bottom of the question if you actually seen it so yes it does have to do with vb6.. in fact I've started porting it from vb6 to C# and thats where the whole problem began in the first place, but yes...... it does in fact have nothing to do with vb6 at the end.. but the progress sure does to me.. but ahhhhhh who gives a fuk forget it man...

Comment: am sorry if you felt so. very sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it guys!, turns out you may use `byte*` in `C#` as one of the parameters if you declare the DLLImport as unsafe.

Like so

```
[DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern unsafe int DisAssemble(IntPtr Data, uint BaseAddress, byte* DisAsmString, out DisAsmStruct DisAsmS, uint DisasmOpt);
```

usage requires 2 fixed statements as I couldn't figure out how to do it in 1 fixed statement it didn't work with comas how suggested by research.

```
unsafe
{
    byte[] OpcodesBuffer = new byte[128];

    fixed (byte* dataPtr = &GLOBALDATA.FDATA[CNT])
    {
        fixed (byte* OpcodesPointer = &OpcodesBuffer[0])
        {
            BufferLength = ModuleASM.DisAssemble(new IntPtr((void*)dataPtr), BaseAddress + CNT, OpcodesPointer, out DisA, 0);
            MessageBox.Show(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(OpcodesBuffer, 0, BufferLength));
            CNT += DisA.Instruction_Length;
         }
    }
}
```